# Using Django SMTP

Tags: python, django, email

After reading the docs on the Django website, I'm a little confused on how to configure the SMTP backend with my Djagno application. I have a local exchange server that is running a business domain `business.com` that uses Outlook as the client. How do I configure the settings so that I am using a corporate email (local exchange) to send emails in the settings?

Thanks for you help!

**EDIT:**

Here is the connection error:

```
email.send()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 342, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 58, in open
    self.connection = connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 335, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 306, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 711, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\Evan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\socket.py", line 702, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

And here is my code:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'business.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '25' 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'purchases@business.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Raise a request to your SMTP services team to allow sending emails from your ip/domain name with a valid sender email id.
2. After it is approved, fetch the details of the EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT from smtp services team. And add it to settings.py as shown below:

   ```
   EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
   EMAIL_HOST = 'business.com'
   EMAIL_PORT = '25' #or 587 or any others
   EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'mailer@business.com' #Same as the sender email id 
   EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword' #For exchange server pwd is not required
   ```
3. Run interactive mode:

   ```
   python manage.py shell
   ```
4. Import the EmailMessage module:

   ```
   from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
   ```
5. Now try to send an email with help of following code:

   ```
   email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', to=['your@email.com'])
   email.send()
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Two questions, why do we use TLS over SSL, and I will have to make a mailbox for Django to use, correct?

Comment: 1. TLS is used for port 587 and SSL is for 465. Both are used for secure connections to SMTP server. For ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/

2. Yes you have to create a mailbox/distribution-list specific for your project and give the same while raising SMTP request.

Comment: I tried to send an email in the shell, however I'm getting WinError 100061 where the target machine is actively refusing the connection. I'm not sure why this is happening as I have sent email manually between my email and the mailbox for the app.

Comment: Please post the exact stack trace of the error, for a quicker resolution.

Comment: Ok, I'll add it to my question above

Comment: It might be a case of firewall issue. Are you trying to send mail from the registered domain/ip(which u raised request for) or from localhost? If localhost then connection will not happen successfully.

Comment: I am trying from a local host, how can I solve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136780/discussion-between-abijith-mg-and-evan).